# What are the penalties for two-weapon-fighting when attacking with unarmed strikes and holding a shield?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm playing a level 1 brawler in PFS. As I'm looking ahead to Brawler's Flurry, I'm curious about how two-weapon fighting penalties are applied.

If I'm holding a heavy steel shield in one hand, and I use Brawler's Flurry to attack with two unarmed attacks (e.g.: my other hand and one of my feet), is my penalty -2/-2 because the two weapons I'm using are light, or is it -4/-4 because I'm holding a heavy object in one of my hands? If I carry the heavy shield in my main hand does that make a difference in calculating these penalties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The penalties apply from the weapons you are using, not the weapons you are holding.  From [Two-Weapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-fighting-combat---final):

> Benefit: Your penalties on attack rolls for fighting with two weapons are reduced.

It doesn't matter where the weapons are wielded, it matters what the weapons are.  Since *unarmed strikes* are considered light weapons, **the penalty is -2/-2**.

Additionally, from [Brawler's Flurry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/brawler#TOC-Brawler-s-Flurry-Ex-):

> She does not need to use two different weapons to use this ability.

This means that the *two-weapon fighting* can actually be done with the same fist, one foot, both feet, or any other combination (including elbows and knees, from the Brawler's [Unarmed Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/brawler#TOC-Unarmed-Strike)).  Your hands could be full of items that aren't usable as weapons (and are extremely heavy, within your heavy load), and you could still use the *Flurry* with the normal penalties.